Convert dataframe to sf object
As can be seen below, the geometry column somehow turns to be a "list" object.
In this case, st_sf does not work, saying no simple features geometry column present. Any ideas?
> head(double_early_1995, 20)
# A tibble: 20 × 4
   yield pattern      year  geometry                                                                                              
   <dbl> <chr>        <chr> <chr>                                                                                                 
 1 4380. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.2259, 117.2659, 117.2659, 117.2259, 117.2259, 31.5508, 31.5508, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.5508))
 2 4691. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.2659, 117.3059, 117.3059, 117.2659, 117.2659, 31.5508, 31.5508, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.5508))
 3 3941. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.3059, 117.3459, 117.3459, 117.3059, 117.3059, 31.5508, 31.5508, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.5508))
 4 4286. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.3459, 117.3859, 117.3859, 117.3459, 117.3459, 31.5508, 31.5508, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.5508))
 5 4012. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.1459, 117.1859, 117.1859, 117.1459, 117.1459, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.5108))
 6 4413. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.1859, 117.2259, 117.2259, 117.1859, 117.1859, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.5108))
 7 3897. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.2659, 117.3059, 117.3059, 117.2659, 117.2659, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.5108))
 8 3857. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.3059, 117.3459, 117.3459, 117.3059, 117.3059, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.5108))
 9 3810. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.3459, 117.3859, 117.3859, 117.3459, 117.3459, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.5108))
10 3787. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.3859, 117.4259, 117.4259, 117.3859, 117.3859, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.5108))
11 3844. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.9059, 117.9459, 117.9459, 117.9059, 117.9059, 31.5108, 31.5108, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.5108))
12 4281. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.0659, 117.1059, 117.1059, 117.0659, 117.0659, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))
13 3509. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.1059, 117.1459, 117.1459, 117.1059, 117.1059, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))
14 3704. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.1459, 117.1859, 117.1859, 117.1459, 117.1459, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))
15 4431. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.1859, 117.2259, 117.2259, 117.1859, 117.1859, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))
16 4532. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.2259, 117.2659, 117.2659, 117.2259, 117.2259, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))
17 3908. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.2659, 117.3059, 117.3059, 117.2659, 117.2659, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))
18 3839. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.3059, 117.3459, 117.3459, 117.3059, 117.3059, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))
19 3846. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.3859, 117.4259, 117.4259, 117.3859, 117.3859, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))
20 3780. Double_Early 1995  list(c(117.4259, 117.4659, 117.4659, 117.4259, 117.4259, 31.4708, 31.4708, 31.4308, 31.4308, 31.4708))

I followed the comments and the problem has been fixed using the code below.
double_early_1995 <- double_early_1995 %>%
  mutate(geometry = st_sfc(lapply(geometry, 
                                  function(coords) { st_polygon(list(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(substr(coords, 8, (nchar(coords) - 2)), ", "))), 
                                                                            ncol = 2, byrow = F)))}))) 


It seems like the geometry column in your data is being read as a list of coordinates instead of a proper geometry column that the sf package can work with.

Would be good to know what geometry corresponds to. LINESTRING?

And, what turned it into a list?

Looks more like a string column (tibble header states <chr>) generated through dput() . What's the data source / source process?  Was there an attempt to store geometries in a CSV?

The raw data were tiffs. I performed some spatial operations and merged the data in tiffs into a data frame, which then was saved in a local machine using write_csv. The data in the post were read_csv from the saved csv file.

If that remote resource is still available, I'd ather review and fix that process. There are many possible (working!) aproaches for what you described, but in this case there's also a strong hint that you used less than optimal methods at some point that led to a data loss (like unclassing and flattening sfc object)

Thanks @margusl The raw data are raster. I ended up converting to raster data instead.

The following conversion may help
double_early_1995 <- double_early_1995 %>%
 mutate(geometry = st_sfc(lapply(geometry, function(coords) { st_polygon(list(matrix(coords, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))) }))) 

Set the CRS (example: WGS84)
st_crs(double_early_1995) <- 4326 

Convert the data frame to an sf object
double_early_1995_sf <- st_as_sf(double_early_1995)

